# Open to use styling?

Tags: react-big-calendar

I am working on a react typescript project using react-big-calendar, but I am bad at styling and I do not really like the way the calendar looks out of the box. Does anyone know where I could get some styles for my calendar?

I have tried online tutorials but I cannot really find any pre-made styles for the calendar.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, or other off-site resources (such as *styles for my calendar*) are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.